# Part number for this Molex 4 pin wire-to-board connector (or similar: Foxconn, Wieson, Tyco, etc)

Tags: pwm, fan, header

I'm having a really hard time finding the correct PN for a 4 pin header, used with PWM fans.

The header I'm looking for is a 4 pin one, similar to the Molex 47053-1000, but a right angle one.

I've already spent a couple of hours on Digikey and the Molex website, but I can't find this. I'm only finding a 4 pin connector that has a bigger plastic tab, that won't take the 4 pin PWM fan connectors.

Has anyone worked with this type of connector before that could provide me the PN?

Here is an image of the type of connectors:
[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I fear this borders on a shopping question (off-topic). Though it is also part identification (on-topic, usually). In any case I've never been able to find them, so I'm curious to find their part number.

Comment: [Related SuperUser Question](https://superuser.com/q/1140923/180661), though that only identifies the vertical part, not the right-angle part.

Comment: @Tom Foxconn only has the vertical listed also [PHF2704E-M1](http://www.fit-foxconn.com/Product/ProductDetail?topClassID=Connector&&PN=HF2704E-M1)

Comment: Yep, I'm finding plenty of vertical ones but right-angle ones are being elusive

Comment: The part number I'm finding references 2510-AW as a part number, but the tab isn't positioned correctly. The vertical version shows it offset though... : https://www.moddiy.com/products/4%252dPin-%283%252b1%29-Male-Fan-Connector-%252d-Black.html

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go ghetto style on this... I'll get the breakable right angle male pin headers, the vertical  4 pin headers, and swap out the metal pins with some pliers...

Comment: Could you ask whoever manufactured the board you showed? The purpose is to allow either a 3- or a 4-pin fan to be connected.

Comment: If you need one as a one off, you can simply get a standard 4-way right-angle KK connector, and take a knife to it to make the tab smaller. That's what I ended up doing for one board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for 2510-4AW and 3+1 on aliexpress turns up [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32961935772.html), which seem to be exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this- despite spending a lot of time on digikey/mouser/molex, I was giving up. It's unfortuate they aren't "officially" available, and also that most people answering this (here and elsewhere) miss the "right angle" and/or "offset tab" part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but, for future reference, I found this on Aliexpress "within" the PN 2510 2.54 mm KF2510 3+1P KF2510-4AW.

I say "within", because there's normally only one search result with that, and the listing has the connectors in question.

Cheers!