# Part number Molex 4 pin wire-to-board connector and 2 pin wire-to-board like Corsair CommanderPro

Tags: pwm, fan, thermistor, header

I'm having a really hard time finding the correct PN for a 4 pin header, used with PWM fans.

The header I'm looking for is a 4 pin one, similar to the Molex 47053-1000, but a right angle one.

I've already spent a couple of hours on Digikey and the Molex website, but I can't find this. I'm only finding a 4 pin connector that has a bigger plastic tab, that won't take the 4 pin PWM fan connectors.

Has anyone worked with this type of connector before that could provide me the PN?

I also wanted to find 2 pin thermistor connectors

Here is an image of the type of connectors:

[image]

It is in the opposite direction.

[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349324/part-number-for-this-molex-4-pin-wire-to-board-connector-or-similar-foxconn-w

Comment: omg, i have sayd - that wrong side..

Comment: u so very smartly man..